# Laravel 7 force user to enter password

Tags: laravel

I want to know how can I force user to re-enter his password on certain route action?

Let say if user wants to edit product before save process happens he has to input his password and if it was correct then saving is allowed.

Is there any default middleware for password in laravel 7? or should i make myself?
What do you suggest?

## Update

I've found [this](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#password-confirmation) but it's only work on web routes, i need same thing to work on API routes.

Problem with this middleware is that it except `sessions` which is only available on web middlewares. I tried to add `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,` into `api` middleware but still getting this error

> RuntimeException: Session store not set on request.

Comment: Is this what you looking for? https://laravel-news.com/new-password-confirmation-in-laravel-6-2

Comment: @AH.Pooladvand actually i'm looking for this https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#password-confirmation but for API routes

Answer (score 1):

For those who stumble on this, the solution is setting `config('password_timeout')` to 1 i.e 1 second.

```
'password_timeout' => 1,
```

You might think that setting it to 0 should work but it doesn't and that's because of this line in the constructor of the `Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword` class

```
$this->passwordTimeout = $passwordTimeout ?: 10800;
```

which defaults `$this->passwordTimeout` to 3 hours when `config('password_timeout')` is not set (null) or 0.

The RequirePassword middleware is being bound to the application container in the `registerRequirePassword` method of the `Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider` class

Answer (score 0):

Why not just rewrite `shouldConfirmPassword()` method?

Session is only used to check when was the password confirmed at. If you are requiring password confirmation every time, just rewrite the method to return true:

```
    /**
     * Determine if the confirmation timeout has expired.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function shouldConfirmPassword($request)
    {
        return true;
        //$confirmedAt = time() - $request->session()->get('auth.password_confirmed_at', 0);

        //return $confirmedAt > config('auth.password_timeout', 10800);
    }
```

Comment: only use `return true`? where it checks if password is correct?

Comment: So this is part of `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/RequirePassword.php` class. You can see the registration logic there. This method only checks the time of last password confirmation. Not to override Laravel native method, you can create and register your own middleware copying this class and just returning true for this method (the constructor and `handle()` should stay the same)